# Vue accessing event listener values between methods

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vue-component

I have the following code below. How can I set the value of "e.detail.name" to "nodeName" and then call it in another method within the same component so I can use the value for an API call.

```
data() {
  return {
      nodeName: '',
      },
     }
getNodeClicked() {
    window.addEventListener('node_clicked', (e) => { console.log(e.detail.name) })
  },
```

Comment: We can not give answer to your question because we don't know if it's a parent component or a child component. For a child components, you should pass it through props. For a parent component, you should emit the value.

Comment: I need the value within the same component just a different method @Wimanicesir

Comment: Oh, i'm sorry. I misread. Just use this.nodeName = e.detail.name then. You can use this.nodeName in any method :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't it just this (am I missing something?):

```js
data() {
  return {
      nodeName: '',
  },
}
getNodeClicked() {
    window.addEventListener('node_clicked', (e) => this.nodeName = e.detail.name)
},
```

Comment: Ya this works, this is what I was doing at first but its the first time I did something like this so I wanted to make sure I was on the right track. Thank you